# How to make a call with the Twitter V2 API

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using the below code to search Tweets with the query parameter. This works fine with the Twitter V1 API, but not with the V2, and after extensively reading their API documentation, I'm confused.

My first question is, do the V1 and V2 share the same authentication? i.e. can I make a call to the V2 with this code, assuming my end point url is correct which leads to the second question, if I can make a call to the V2 with the same auth as the V1, what's the correct end point? the notable differences so far is the query parameter which is "q" for the V1 and "query" for the V2. Then apparently the .json is not needed, but I tried both at the end of the V2 end point and still I get the same error:

```
stdClass Object ( [client_id] => 131XXXXXX [detail] => When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal. [registration_url] => https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview [title] => Client Forbidden [required_enrollment] => Standard Basic [reason] => client-not-enrolled [type] => https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden )
```

```
    include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/TwitterAPIExchange.php");
     
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
        'consumer_key' => "xxx",
        'consumer_secret' => "xxx"
    );
    
    //$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
    
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent";
    
    $requestMethod = "GET";
    
    // V1
    //$getfield = '?q=bitcoin';
    
     // V2
    $getfield = '?query=bitcoin';
     
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                        ->performRequest();
     
    $tweets = json_decode($response);
      
    print_r($tweets);
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like the V1 and V2 can share the same auth: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/migrate/standard-to-twitter-api-v2

*OAuth 1.0a User Context and OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token authentication
The v1.1 search/tweets and the Twitter API v2 recent search endpoint support both OAuth 1.0a User Context and OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token.
Therefore, if you were previously using the standard v1.1 search endpoint you can continue using the same authentication method if you migrate to the Twitter API v2 version.*

Answer (score 3):

First you have to add the app you’re using to a “Project” on the Developer dashboard. This step is necessary to be able to call v2 endpoints see: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview

I got this answer from the twitter community forum and now it works fine with the code posted in my question above.

Comment: I'm getting this error even if i have access v2 endpoints, please refer to this https://twittercommunity.com/t/v2-api-endpoints-throwing-error-client-not-enrolled/158144